# Symfony2 custom login modifying the default system

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony2, and i have read most of the book, it all makes perfect sense i really like the framework.

But, i am trying to achive the following:

I have a login system, this system authenticates on another site via CURL, so the users will not be in my database, a successful login depends on the response i get from an external site.

System flow is:

User enters credentials.

I CURL the external site.

If the external site accepts the credentials, i store their credentials in the database.

I log them in

So, id like to have everything symfony2 offers in therms of automatic redirection, etc etc, i would just like to set the logged in session manually.

How would i go about configuring my security.yml and how do i set the "Logged in" sessions that they set to achieve this?

I have a users entity, with all the methods they recommend in their tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should understand the difference between [Authentication and Authorization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) in symfony

Then what you want is to create a [custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) that will take care of finding who the user is and it's where you should do your curl requests to the other service.

After that you have to deal with Authorization, which is the part that takes care of finding if a user has the privilege of doing/access something, this is where you setup the ACL's.

If you're not storing the users in your database or in-memory but getting them for the service you should also implement a [custom user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) that will grab the users from the service.